# bulk update by Stored procedures of complex type cosmosDB azure

Tags: javascript, c#, azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I try to update bulk of complex documents in cosomosdb via stored procedures in server side.
My client side is developed in C#.

I want to implement stored procedure, that update the details of course to list of students, I want to update the course details for all students that belong to list of **ids** with given **courseDetiels**

1. How I create query that return all the document with id that contain in the ids parameter.

2.How I can update complex-object for example:

```
   public class CourseDetiels : Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Resource
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public String CName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("finalGrade")]
    public double FinalGrade{ get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("GradesInWorks")]
    public double[] GradesInWorks{ get; set; }
```

}

I need to update the only the courses that taken by the user in specific semester in Courses dictionary in Student class:

```
    public class Student: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Resource
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public String ID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Courses")]
    public Dictionary<string, CourseDetiels> Courses{ get; set; }

}
```

This is the pseudo code I want to write....

```
function UpdateCourses(ids,courseDetiels) {

   var collection = getContext().getCollection();
   var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
   var response = getContext().getResponse();
   var docCount = 0;
   var counter = 0;

   UpdateCoursesByIds(ids,complexObject);

   function UpdateCoursesByIds(ids,complexObject,continuation) {
        var query = {
            query: "select * from root c where ...." **//how to select only documents that contains in ids??**
        };

        var requestOptions = {
            continuation: continuation
        };

        var isAccepted =
            collection
            .queryDocuments(collectionLink,
                            query,
                            requestOptions,
                            function queryCallback(err, documents, responseOptions) {
                                     if (err) throw err;
                                     if (documents.length > 0) {
                                        // If at least one document is found, update it.
                                        docCount = documents.length;
                                        for (var i=0; i<docCount; i++){
                                            UpdateDoc(documents[i]);
                                        }
                                        response.setBody("Updated " + docCount + " documents");
                                      }
                                      else if (responseOptions.continuation) {
                                        UpdateCoursesByIds(responseOptions.continuation);
                                      } else {
                                             throw new Error("Document not found.");
                                             }
                            });

        if (!isAccepted) {
            throw new Error("The stored procedure timed out");
        }
    }

    function UpdateDoc(document) {
        //Optimistic concurrency control via HTTP ETag.
        var requestOptions = { etag: document._etag };

        **//I NEED TO UPDATE ONLY THE COURSES THAT TAKEN ....**

        var isAccepted = collection
                         .replaceDocument(document._self,
                                          document,
                                          requestOptions,
                                          function replaceCallback(err, updatedDocument, responseOptions) {
                                                   if (err) throw err;
                                                   counter++;
                                           });

        // If we hit execution bounds - throw an exception.
        if (!isAccepted) {
            throw new Error("The stored procedure timed out");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.How I create query that return all the document with id that contain in the ids parameter.

You could use IN operator in Azure Cosmos [SQL APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query#Advanced) as below :

> SELECT *
>       FROM c
>       WHERE c.id in ("1","2",....,"10")

```
var idsArrString="";
for(var i = 0;i<ids.length;i++){
   idsArrString+="'"+ids[i]+"',";
}

idsArrString=idsArrString.substr(0,idsArrString.length-1);

var query = {
   query: "select * from root c where c.id in ("+ idsArrString + ")";
};
```

> 2.How I can update complex-object

According to your need , I created a stored procedure as below :

```
    function sample(idsArrayString,courses) {
        var collection = getContext().getCollection();

        // Query documents as you want
        var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
            collection.getSelfLink(),
// 1:Please replace the ("1","2") with your idsArrayString

            'SELECT * FROM root r where r.id in ("1","2")',
            function (err, feed, options) {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (!feed || !feed.length) getContext().getResponse().setBody('no docs found');
                else {
                    for(var i = 0;i<feed.length;i++){
                        var doc = feed[i];
// 2:Please replace "maths" with your courses obj
                        doc.course = "maths";
                        collection.replaceDocument(doc._self,doc,                           function(err) {
                                 if (err) throw err;
                     });
                    }
                    getContext().getResponse().setBody(JSON.stringify("success"));
                }
            });

        if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
    }
```

Note that two comments in the code replace them with your own arguments.

Then you could execute Stored Procedure in your C# code:

```
// execute the stored procedure
client.executeStoredProcedureAsync('dbs/testdb/colls/testColl/sprocs/<your stored procedure id>')
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.result); 
    }, function (err) {
        console.log("Error", error);
    });
```

More details , please refer to this [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#stored-procedures).

Hope it helps you.

---

Update Answer :

You could update your courseDetails in doc as below with the above comment 2 :

```
doc.courseDetails.finalGrade = "50";
```

Please refer to the sample code as below which mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#stored-procedures) I provided

```
client.executeStoredProcedureAsync('dbs/testdb/colls/testColl/sprocs/createMyDocument',
              <your arguments>);
```

---

Update Answer 2:

I created sample document as you offered.

```
{
    "id": "4",
    "StudenName": "Jay",
    "Courses": {
        "Math": {
            "Grade": "A",
            "Place": "NYU"
        },
        "Phys": {
            "Grade": "B",
            "Place": "MIT"
        }
    },
    "Rank": "AA"
}
```

Then I modify the **comment 2** in above stored procedure javascript code to replace the **Grade** with "C".

```
for(var i = 0;i<feed.length;i++){
                    var doc = feed[i];
                    var cources = doc.Courses;
                    for (var key in cources) {
                        if (cources.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            console.log(key + " -> " + cources[key]);
                            cources[key].Grade ="C";
                        }
                    }
                    doc.Courses = cources;
                    collection.replaceDocument(doc._self,doc, 
                    function(err) {
                             if (err) throw err;
                 });
                }
```

Changed document:

```
{
    "id": "4",
    "StudenName": "Jay",
    "Courses": {
        "Math": {
            "Grade": "C",
            "Place": "NYU"
        },
        "Phys": {
            "Grade": "C",
            "Place": "MIT"
        }
    },
    "Rank": "AA"
}
```

Comment: thanks for your helpful answer ,but I still have some miss understood , 1. My doc.courses is a dictionary type (each item is key, courseDetails like in C# ) , so how I can update the specific course , in the dictionary .2 How I pass to the stored procedure the argument when I execute the stored procedure ? ,Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I asking :-) , like you can see in the origin question , every Student have dictionary  with the courses he take (each course is a pair of courseID,CourseDetials)  (each student have many courses not only one) , When I call the store procedure I want to update only the specific course details (by id) in the dictionary ... Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @MAK Would you please enter this char room to discuss your issue? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161506/jaymak